# How do I exclude a .css file from loading in application.scss in Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

I have YooTheme and Bootstrap and they are interfering with each other. The designer used YooTheme for the home page and I don't have time to translate it. How do I include `yootheme.css` only for the index page, and exclude it from the header everywhere else? I have

`application.haml` - Layout

```
/ UIkit CSS
-# %link{:rel => "stylesheet", :href => "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.30/css/uikit.min.css"}/
%link{:rel => "stylesheet", :crossorigin => "anonymous", :href => "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css", :integrity => "sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ"}/
= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
```

`application.scss`

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

`app/assets/stylesheets/yootheme.css`

`index.haml`

```
=stylesheet_link_tag 'yootheme.css', media: :all
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`sprockets#stub`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#the-stub-directive) and the filename to exclude in your application.css file, in order to prevent its load:

```
*= stub yootheme.css
```

And then to incorporate it manually, you have to add the file to your `assets.rb`, restart your server, and load the file by yourself using the `stylesheet_link_tag` helper:

```
# config/initializers/assets.rb
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( yootheme.css )

# view
= stylesheet_link_tag 'yootheme.css', media: :all
```

Comment: Nifty - but your should avoid sprockets directives in SASS/SCSS as they don't play nice with the Sass compiler. I also really don't see how this would be worked into a compile on deployment setup.

Comment: Or do you leave the `*= stub yootheme.css` directive in there and is the restart to trigger assets recomplilation?

Answer (score 3):

### Don't use require_tree in SASS/SCSS

> Sprockets provides some directives that are placed inside of comments
>   called require, require_tree, and require_self. 
>   **DO NOT USE THEM IN YOUR SASS/SCSS FILES.** They are very primitive and do not work well with Sass files. Instead, use Sass's native
>   @import directive which sass-rails has customized to integrate with
>   the conventions of your Rails projects.
>   https://github.com/rails/sass-rails

If you are not using any Sass features such as variables, functions, mixins etc you'll get by fine with `require_tree`. But soon as you do you will realize that they are not available in any file except in the one they are declared. Thats because each file is run in the SASS compiler before Sprockets concatenates the files together.

So you are better off using `@import 'foo'` and manually declaring which files and the order they should be added to the compiled stylesheet.

### Its not as bad as it sounds

The default assets pipeline setup is a pretty good attempt to get lazy programmers not to shove everything into a single css/js file while still compiling it to single optimized file. It really requires `require_tree .` to make sense.

I usually turn off the assets generator:

```
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.generators do |g|
      g.assets false
      # or
      g.stylesheets false
    end
  end
end
```

Instead I deliberately organize the code in `app/assets` into modules. And any code that is not mine goes into `/vendor`.

You can use [glob imports](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#glob-imports) to import sass mixins and varibles from library folders - but it cannot/should not replace `require_tree`.

### Using content_for instead of separate layouts

Using a seperate layout means that you have to duplicate the entire file just to change a line or two.

Instead you can use [`content_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html) to make dynamic chunks in a layout:

```
# application.html.haml:
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title My Rails app
    - content_for :assets
      = stylesheet_link_tag "application"
      = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = csrf_meta_tag

  %body
    = yield
```

Then later in the `index` template we can add to the `head` section:

```
- content_for :assets
  = stylesheet_link_tag "some_other_file"
```

This would add the stylesheet link under `= javascript_include_tag "application"` as  content_for concatenates the provided block to the content that is already captured. Use `flush: true` to discard any previously provided content (by the layout).

```
- content_for :assets, flush: true
  = stylesheet_link_tag "some_other_file"
```

Comment: Even if you are not using sass the greedy `require_tree` directive in sprockets offers no control over how files are included (its alphabetically). In CSS thats bullocks as directives have priority in the order they are defined. So my real take away is beware of `require_tree`.

Comment: "Thats because each file is run in the SASS compiler before Sprockets concatenates the files together." That explains why I have to repeat `@import "colors.scss";` in all my files.

Answer (score 0):

***something like this***

index.haml(layout)
..

```
- if action_name=="index"
   /* include both application.css and yootheme.css for index*/
   = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', 'yootheme.css', media: :all
- else
   /* include only application.css*/
   =stylesheet_link_tag 'application, media: :all
```

Comment: Both layouts will still have `stylesheet_link_tag    'application'` and it will still include `yootheme.css`. How do I exclude `yootheme.css`?

Comment: @Chloe check above answer. You can do action based asset loading

Answer (score 0):

scss_files: 'app/assets/stylesheets/**/*.css.scss'

exclude: 'app/assets/stylesheets/plugins/**'

linters:
BorderZero:
enabled: false

Indentation:
exclude:
- 'path/to/file.scss'
- 'path/to/directory/**'
severity: warning
width: 2